# A Programmers Riddle

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

A programmer friend left me a riddle:

```
Loop

if riddle is answered then exit

else 

All human kind is subject to this negativity

nothing is true in life except these two things

concatenate the synonyms into a string to uncover an error

terminate due to this error and the riddle is answered

end if;

end loop;
```

This particular riddle doesn't compile can you figure it out?

Edit: The psuedocode is there for a reason. not everyone needs to be a programmer to solve this riddle. Although this forward thinking is a hint.

Comment: What's the point of the loop if it terminates on the first iteration either way? :)

Comment: @Riley it definitely doesn't.

Comment: @Riley It wouldn't truly end on the first iteration for everyone. It may take someone several tries to answer the riddle, thus the loop starts over.

Comment: @ITAlex I wouldn't say it definitely doesn't, as this means that no one can solve it on their first attempt. For most, it will execute more than once.

Comment: I suppose we can't really  say what will happen because the code won't even compile.

Comment: Missing some comment blocks and all that invalid syntax there. :D

Comment: @PerpetualJ They would have to iterate to the riddle and then answer it for at least 2 loops

Comment: @Riley how can `if riddle is answered then exit` be satisfied on the first iteration, before any attempt to solve it?

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't say it would go down that branch. But if it did, it would exit the loop. If it didn't, then it would terminate due to the error. I'm not asserting that my interpretation is the only correct one. We don't even know what programming language this is after all.

Comment: @WeatherVane Because if Riley were to answer it on his first attempt, the next time the conditional is hit, then the loop is exited. Granted, this is not technically a `while` loop and the conditional is within it making it more of a `do-while`.

Comment: @Riley oh you did: *What's the point of the loop if it terminates on the first iteration either way?* That cannot be satisified on the first iteration.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure where you see a contradiction in my reasoning. If you want to continue to debate, let's carry it into [Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) instead of the comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm think the answer is:

> Syntax

Since

All human kind is subject to this negativity

> Sin

nothing is true in life except these two things

> "Our new Constitution is now established, and has an appearance that promises permanency; but in this world nothing can be said to be certain, except **death and taxes**." — Benjamin Franklin (although not the origin of the idiom)

concatenate the synonyms into a string to uncover an error
(& This particular riddle doesn't compile)

> Sin + Tax -> "Syn" + "Tax" -> "Syntax"
>  A syntax error is when when the code cannot be parsed correctly for compilation/execution

Comment: I am pretty sure you are right, so +1, but if you are, the riddle suggests to me a misunderstanding that ****** is inherently a kind of *****, rather than there existing *****s relating to ******.

Comment: Many l*******s have ****** *****s maybe the riddle just needs to have "type of" inserted at the appropriate place. (If I understood you correctly.)

Comment: You understood correctly and I think I agree that that would work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is:

> begin and end - Only two things are true in life, birth and death.

Your code is missing (based on syntax):

> The keyword `begin` which denotes your loop should begin, the `end` keyword requires a matching `begin`.

For example:

> Begin Loop .... End Loop - also - Else Begin
>  
>  In C#: while (notSolved) { /* Riddle */ }

Also:

> You need to put the riddle in as comments. The riddle in itself is a syntactical error that will not compile until commented out.

Comment: Nice attempt. I would revisit line 5

Comment: Line 5 states to use the synonyms for the only two things that are true in life. What did I miss there?

Comment: your original idea is only half correct.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> bell

All human kind is subject to this negativity

> this applies to the next sentence

nothing is true in life except these two things

> death and taxes

concatenate the synonyms into a string to uncover an error

> `death knell` or `death toll` (toll ~ tax). As some tolling (or knelling) seems to be also involved, it's an error that only death and taxes are true in life -- a bell (of some sort) is implicated. So we

terminate due to this error

> of forgetting the `bell`

and the riddle is answered

> As an aside, ASCII character 7 is BEL (bell). And there are 7 lines inside the loop (just overthinking)